# Grizzly 2.2 adding static resources

Tags: scala, web-applications, grizzly

How do i add static html resources to Grizzly 2.2 server? I tried

```
val server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, new ResourceConfig())
val statichandler = new StaticHttpHandler()
statichandler.addDocRoot("/webapp")
statichandler.start
server.getServerConfiguration.addHttpHandler(statichandler)
server.start
```

webapp folder is inside src/main/resource in a maven project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
val statichandler = new StaticHttpHandler(<path>, "/webapp");
server.getServerConfiguration.addHttpHandler(statichandler);
```

Where `<path>` is the absolute path to the resources you wish to serve.

Comment: well this works, what i intended to ask was what if resources are inside jar file. For which you need to write custom http hnadler. Examples can be found in jersey 2.x.

Comment: See http://grizzly-nio.net/2013/08/grizzly-2-3-3-serving-static-http-resources-from-jar-files/